# Data step to compare date value with its predecessor line value

Tags: sas

How can I compare Date column with same value but in previous line?

I have a dataset with the following data:

```
 Nr            Date               DocumentDate
 1              17APR2019          3APR2019       
 1              31MAY2019          6APR2019
 1              26APR2019         18APR2019
 2              22APR2019          5APR2019
 2               1MAY2019          6APR2019
 2              14APR2019          8APR2019
```

DocumentDate is the date where the line enter to the dataset.

I want to accomplish another dataset with the following information. This dataset is a tracking of how 'Date' column has been changed.

```
 Order   DateBefore       NewDate           DocumentDate
 1          .              17APR2019        3APR2019
 1       17APR2019         31MAY2019        6APR2019
 1       31MAY2019         26APR2019       18APR2019
 2           .             22APR2019        5APR2019
 2       22APR2019          1MAY2019        6APR2019
 2        1MAY2019         14APR2019        8APR2019
```

How to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily using the `LAG()` function.

Use BY group processing to make sure you don't use the date from previous group on the first observation of a new group.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by NR ;
  datebefore=lag(date);
  if first.nr then datebefore=.;
  format datebefore date9.;
run;
```

Make sure to run the LAG() function on every observation since it does NOT return the value from the previous observation, but instead returns the value from the previous execution of that LAG() function call.